# Redshift + Collapse

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravitational-redshift, gravitational-collapse

Let a radio transmitter on the surface of a collapsing spherical star emit monochromatic waves, let the distant observer, at the same theta and phi, as the transmitter, receive the waves. Show that at late times the wavelength received varies as: $\lambda_{rec}/\lambda_{em} = k*e^{t/4M}$. t is distant observer proper time measured.

I am assuming the Schwarzschild metric here.
The only i could imagine to do is to find a relation between the times,
$d_{\tau} = \int \sqrt{(1-2M/R)(dt/d\lambda)^2}d\lambda$,

but i am not sure if this is the right way, i thought that we could call lambda as r, the distance from the surface, so that $dt/d\lambda = 1/c = 1$, even so, i wouldn't know how to proceed after the integral.

Comment: Aren't you just calculating the red shift for a transmitter falling freely into the Schwarzschild metric? The fact the transmitter is at the surface of a collapsing star is irrelevant.